# Displaying XY data incorrectly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, display, xy

I received the following coordinates for a project in Peru. I have used the correct projection (PSAD 1956 UTM Zone 19S/ WKID 24879), which never shows up in the correct destination. They should be plotted somewhere near Mancora, Peru. What is going on?

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The values listed as lon and lat in the first table are not longitude and latitude, the second table has it correct, they are eastings and northings

Comment: longitude and latitude are degrees, ranging from -180 to +180 for the former and -90 to +90 for the latter. Your numbers are, by definition, *not* longitude and latitude. They probably are meters, so projected coordinates.

Comment: The correct one is PSAD56 / UTM zone 17S EPSG:24877, see https://epsg.io/map#srs=24877&x=499763.11420633463&y=9541067.71991097&z=9&layer=streets

Comment: @TomazicM Thank you for the correct wkid! I got the points in the area now, but when measuring the distance between them, it doesn't match the table for about half of them(a little more in length than supposed to be). I understand they are easting/northings, so am I supposed to convert them before trying to plot them? I tried using an online converter, but it doesn't read the latitude (since it has 7 digits instead of 6). Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Since points are so close you can use Cartesian geometry on projected coordinates to calculate distance, and you'll get the above numbers. As for the rest, I'm not familiar with ArcGIS software (and neither QGIS).

Answer (score 1):

Values:

```
name,eastings,northings
A,492792.8338,9543747.2915
B,492800.7253,9543685.6082
C,492810.1982,9543660.6474
```

Plot in the correct location when using EPSG:24877

[image: map showing correct location of points]